# Vue & Typescript error on nested ref parameters when a nested function is added in a reactive object

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tsc, vue-reactivity

link to reproduce the error : [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-bird-4dsir9?file=/src/index.ts)

In `vue 2.7 & 3`, if I am not mistaken any `ref` nested in a object inside `ref` or a `reactive()` will be unwraped as explaned [here](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive)

This works fine and as expected in the following simple example :

```
interface IName {
  first: string;
  last: string;
  sayHi?: () => void;
}

interface IPerson {
 name: IName;
 isAdult: boolean;
}

const me: IPerson = reactive({
  isAdult: ref(false),
  name: {
    first: ref("first"),
    last: "last"
  },
});
```

No errors are detected and everything is fine since `reactive` unwrap all nested `ref`s and the object is of type `IPerson`

But when I decide to implement the optional function `sayHi: () => void` inside the nested object `name` a `ts` error appears

```
const me: IPerson = reactive({
  isAdult: ref(false), // Type 'Ref<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)
  name: {
    first: ref("first"), // Type 'Ref<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
    last: "last"
  },
  sayHi: function () {
    console.log("Hi !")
  }
});
```

What is stranger is that I found that it's not related to `sayHi` but I get the errors when I add any function at any level of the object `me`. Knowing that when I serve/build my app everything works fine and no erros whatsoever and I don't understand why, is it a typescript bug or limitation or something else

Comment: Somehow that just works for me. Magic ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: Anyway, try ts5, maybe it'll fix?

Comment: @Dimava no it's still not working with TS 5. How did it work for you in a local environment ? Did you try the codesandbox I linked above ?

Comment: it doesn't seem to work in codesandbox, but in local VSCode, typescriptlang.org/play and stackblitz

Comment: is it possible to share a link in stackblitz or other where it working ?

Comment: I got the same issue when I tried to build this code with stackblitz on a new Vite->vue-ts project.